# Windows 8 BackgroundTasks(TimeTrigger)?

Tags: c#, windows-8, background-process, recurrence

I am new to windows 8. I'd like to remind the user about a task stored in my application.

Scheduled notification allows me to raise a toast and update the app's tile to remind the user. But it doesn't support recurrence (repeat feature). So I want to use a background task with time trigger. The documentation says the app should be present on the lock screen.

This is confusing, what exactly does this mean? When will the background task trigger? How can I use it so that it supports recurrence and I can notify the user. Any sample to this would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless you want to install a service this would only be possible while your computer is running. So the simple solution is record the last time the event took place, and keep track when the next event should take place, and use BackgroundTasks ( TimeTrigger ) to display your event.  I don't provide code to questions that attempt the problem on their own, which means, posting their code and explaining the reason its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Time trigger tasks are only available to apps on the lock screen. There is a maintenance task, however, which is available to all apps. Instead of requiring placement on the lock screen, maintenance tasks only run when the device is plugged in to AC power.

See [How to use the maintenance trigger.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh977060.aspx)